# Autoload port forwording in ssh

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I need to forwarding a port to another server through ssh, I made this code to check if the port is open:

```
if lsof -Pi :8080 -sTCP:LISTEN -t > /dev/null ; then
        echo "running"
else
        echo "not running"
        ssh -f -N -L 8080:<destination server>:25 user@<ssh-server> -p11000 > /dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

I run this code through a cron, the code works, but opens many connections to the ssh-server and the server goes down after a few hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a job for `cron`. Use something like `autossh` instead.